# Keep jQuery generated markup between setInterval AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

The script below generates markup in real-time and autoupdates with `setInterval`. Markup consists of `button`s and hidden content in `div`s. A particular button un-hides its corresponding `div`. However, upon each interval the div re-hides. I am trying to keep such particular `div` shown after each interval, post-click. Is there a way for the DOM to remember which `div` was shown prior interval refresh? I am trying to achieve this with front-end JavaScript, no server-side solutions please. Thanks in advance!

```
setInterval(itemMenu,1500);

function itemMenu() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Administration/data/people.xml"
    }).done(function (xml) {

        $("#loadMe").empty();
        $("#toadMe").empty();

        $(xml).find('fullName').each(function(index) {

            ////////////////////////////
            // generate loadMe markup //
            var i = index + 1;
            var fullName = $(this).text();

            $('<button type="button" class="mybutton" name="users" onclick="itemContent(this.value)"></button>').attr('value', i).html(fullName).appendTo('#loadMe');

            ////////////////////////////
            // generate toadMe markup //
            var firstName = $(this).siblings('firstName');
            var lastName = $(this).siblings('lastName');
            var age = $(this).siblings('age');
            var hometown = $(this).siblings('hometown');
            var job = $(this).siblings('job');

            $('<div></div>').attr('id', i).appendTo('#toadMe');
            $('<h1></h1>').html(firstName).appendTo('#' + i);
            $('<h1></h1>').html(lastName).appendTo('#' + i);
            $('<h1></h1>').html(age).appendTo('#' + i);
            $('<h1></h1>').html(hometown).appendTo('#' + i);
            $('<h1></h1>').html(job).appendTo('#' + i);

            $('#'+i).hide();

        });
    }).fail(function (response, error) {
        $('#info').text('Error!');
    });

};

function itemContent(k) {
    $("#"+k).show();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered only generating the `<div>` when the button is clicked instead, so you're not constantly overwriting those elements when the XML is polled? Something like this:

```
setInterval(refreshXml, 1500);

function refreshXml() {
  var req = $.get('Administration/data/people.xml');

  req.done(function(xml) {
    // Update the global XML variable used to create buttons.
    window.peopleXml = xml;

    // Clear existing buttons.
    $('#loadMe').empty();

    // Display a button for each XML person entity.
    $(xml).find('fullName').each(function(index) {
        var fullName = $(this).text();

        $('<button>', {
          'class': 'mybutton',
          value: $(this).siblings('id').text(),
          text: fullName
        }).appendTo('#loadMe');          
    });

    // Update any person divs that were already visible.
    $('#toadMe .person').each(function() {
      // Grabs the ID from data-person-id set earlier.
      var id = $(this).data('person-id');

      show_person(id);
    });
  });
}

function show_person(id) {
  $('#person-detail-' + id).remove();

  get_person(id).appendTo('#toadMe');
}

function get_person(id) {
  var $person = $(window.peopleXml).find('id:contains(' + id + ')').parent();

  var $div = $('<div>', {
    'class': 'person',
    'data-person-id': id,
    id: 'person-detail-' + id
  });

  $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('firstName').text() }).appendTo($div);
  $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('lastName').text() }).appendTo($div);
  $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('age').text() }).appendTo($div);
  $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('hometown').text() }).appendTo($div);
  $('<h1>', { text: $person.find('job').text() }).appendTo($div);

  return $div;  
}

$(document).on('click', '.mybutton', function() {
  show_person(this.value);
});
```

As your XML file grows, this approach will be worthwhile even if it seems a bit more complicated at first. The overhead to pre-generate a `<div>` for every possible `person` every 1.5 seconds would begin to noticeably lag the browser as the XML document gets real-world large.

Comment: Dave, actually I found a syntax error when you were setting values for the buttons, I added `.text()` which seemed to fix the problem. Also, instead of appending to `#toadMe` I need to replace data inside `#toadMe`. I can't remember the function for that though... It looks like this is going to work once I find that function!!! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Sorry about that. I typed it into the textarea here without having a good way to test it.

Comment: Do you want to only allow one person's div to be visible in #toadMe at a given time, or do you want to be sure that only one copy of each person's div appears (i.e. multiple ones could be open, but not duplicates)?

Comment: Dave, actually this is not what I was looking for, I am purposely overwritting the data in order to update the inner data. The `setInterval` needs to apply to all the XML. Can you revise your code in order to do this desired effect?

Comment: I posted your code to my live example, it does not auto-update the `#toadMe` div, just the `#loadMe` buttons. Any ideas?

Comment: Sure, it's not much more work to update already visible divs. I'll update my example.

Comment: Thanks Dave sorry I wasn't more descriptive in my question.

Comment: No problem. Take a look at my update and see if that's closer to what you're after.

Comment: `this.id` in the click handler should have been `this.value`.